# How to get map keys from Arrow dataset

Tags: pyarrow

What is the recommended approach to obtain a unique list of map keys from an Arrow dataset?

For a dataset with schema containing:

```
...
PARQUET:field_id: '19'
detail: map<string, struct<reported: bool, incidents_per_month: int32>
...
```

Sample data:

```
"detail": {"a": {"reported": true, "incidents_per_month: 3}, "b": {"reported": true, "incidents_per_month: 3}},
"detail": {"c": {"reported": false, "incidents_per_month: 3}}
```

What is the right approach to obtaining a list of unique map keys for field detail? i.e. a,b,c

Currrent (slow) approach:

```
map_data = dataset.field('a)
map_keys = list(set([key for chunk in map_data.iterchunks() for key in chunk.keys.unique().tolist()]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You already found the `.keys` attribute of a MapArray. This gives an array of all keys, of which you can take the unique values.

But a dataset (Table) can consist of many chunks, and then accessing the data of a column gives a `ChunkedArray` which doesn't have this `keys` attribute. For that reason, you loop over the different chunks, and combine the unique values of all of those.
For now, looping over the chunks is still needed I think, but calculating the overall uniques can be done a bit more efficiently with pyarrow:

```py
# set-up small example
map_type = pa.map_(pa.string(), pa.struct([('reported', pa.bool_()), ('incidents_per_month', pa.int32())]))
values = [
    [("a", {"reported": True, "incidents_per_month": 3}), ("b", {"reported": True, "incidents_per_month": 3})],
    [("c", {"reported": False, "incidents_per_month": 3})]
]
dataset = pa.table({'detail': pa.array(values, map_type)})

# then creating a chunked array of keys
map_data = dataset.column('detail')
keys = pa.chunked_array([chunk.keys for chunk in map_data.iterchunks()])

# and taking the unique of those in one go:
>>> keys.unique()
<pyarrow.lib.StringArray object at 0x7fbc578af940>
[
  "a",
  "b",
  "c"
]
```

For optimal efficiency, it would still be good to avoid the python loop of `pa.chunked_array([chunk.keys for chunk in map_data.iterchunks()])`, and for this I opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-12564 to track this enhancement.

Comment: Wonderful! I'll post some relative timings compared to my naive approach.